# Geometry Nodes Create Dome From Grid

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a grid of vertices constructed like this

[image]

I would like to adjust the grid so that it pops up like a dome, like this:

[image]

In normal blender, i can just grab the middle 4 vertices and move them along the Z axis. (or a different one if its rotated). How can I achieve this effect with geometry nodes?

Comment: The simplest solution for this is a radial gradient texture, which you use as offset in the node `Set Position`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could e.g. use this node setup:

[image]

[image]

or this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! both options work great

Comment: You are welcome